# Вставка в таблицу только изменившихся данных.

Tags: sql, mysql

Имеется таблица

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discrete_archive` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `dtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `f1` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 `f2` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 `f3` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Ее задача хранить архив значений в полях f1, f2, f3 с меткой времени dtime.
Хотелось бы вставлять данные в таблицу, только в случае если значения f1, f2 или f3 изменилось, чтобы не плодить одинаковых записей.
Помогите реализовать это средствами MySQL?

UPD 1.

Как правильно реализовать нижепреведенный код на MySQL?

```
SET @data_list = SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM discrete_archive ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
IF @data_list != (11,22,33) THEN
    INSERT INTO discrete_archive VALUES (11,22,33);
IF END;
```

1 - Берем последнюю строку и сравниваем ее значения с [11,22,33] (это новые данные)
2 - Если выборки не равны, т.е. в последней строке таблицы f1!=11 or f2!=22 or f3 != 33, 
то выполняем insert и вставляем (11, 22, 33)

Comment: Что-то не совсем понял, как хранить и что? Можно на примере, плиз? (Голова что-то не очень к вечеру соображает.)

Comment: Хранить числа в полях f1, f2, f3.

Comment: Хотелось бы вставлять данные в таблицу, только в случае если значения f1, f2 или f3 изменилось, чтобы не плодить одинаковых записей.

вот это мне не совсем понятно?
допустим у нас есть запись 10, метка времени, 15, 20, 40
и тут мы хотим вставить  новую запись с такмими же числами 15, 20, 40 - и что должно произойти?

Comment: В этом случае ничего, т.к. (15,20,40) не изменилось. Если бы было (30,20,40), тогда insert into discrete_archive values (30,20,40)

Comment: Так погоди - разница между insert и update огромная) у тебя в таблице что, всего одна строка подразумевается?

Comment: update вобще не нужен. Только insert. Данные в таблице должны накапливаться.

Comment: А сравнивать всегда с последними значениями?

К примеру :

последняя  10,20,40  
предпоследняя 30,20,50

и тут вставляем 30,20,50?

Нет, вы, конечно, меня извините, но почему из вас надо все клещами-то тянуть? И тут вставляем 30,20,50? - что должно произойти - всталяем данные, так как они не соответствуют последней, или не вставляем, потому что такое сочетание уже есть в таблице (и без разницы, что не последние по вставке).

Comment: Да, именно такд    
Новые данные должны вставляться, если они отличаются от последней записи (ну или если таблица пустая). Цель - фиксировать изменения параметров с указанием времени, чтобы тренд можно было построить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К примеру, таблица

```
"id"    "dtime" "f1"    "f2"    "f3"
"2" "2014-10-14 23:09:42"   "1" "2" "3"
"3" "2014-10-14 23:09:59"   "2" "3" "4"
```

Лови

```
INSERT INTO `discrete_archive` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`)
select 1 AS `f1`, 2 as `f2`, 3 as `f3`
FROM `discrete_archive`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM 
( select * from `discrete_archive` order by id desc limit 0,1) as t1
WHERE `f1` = 1
and `f2` = 2
and `f3` = 3
)
LIMIT 0,1
```

И на будущее, нормально ставь вопрос.

1-й раз запрос отработает, а потом уже нет, так как после станут значения 1 2 3.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать сделать 2 запросами. Первым выбираем уже записанные значения, делаю сверку с новыми, если хоть один параметр отличается - делаем апдейт поля с временем

Comment: Если только эти 2 запроса выполнить внутри одного.
Подскажите как реализовать следующее:
    http://pastebin.com/MG7JRcYH

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставил ограничение UNIQUE(f1,f2,f3).

Comment: Да я тоже так думал, но кое-как вытянул нормальную постановку задачи в последнем комменте автора.

новые данные должны вставляться, если они отличаются от последней записи (ну или если таблица пустая). Цель - фиксировать изменения параметров с указанием времени, чтобы тренд можно было построить.