# Выборка из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Вопрос по мотивам [моего предыдущего топика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/367662/mysql-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Операции с той же таблицей.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discrete_archive` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`f1` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`f2` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`f3` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Необходимо выбрать из таблицы поля dtime и, например, f1, исключив из выборки идущие подряд строки с одинаковыми значениями f1.

Например. Имеем таблицу:

```
dtime      f1
10:00      1
10:01      2
10:02      4
10:03      4
10:04      2
10:05      7
```

Необходимо выбрать следующее:

```
10:00      1
10:01      2
10:02      4
10:04      2
10:05      7
```

Т.е. запись (10:03      4) не нужна, т.к. она повторяет предыдущую.

Если в таблице 1 запись, то необходимо вернуть ее.
Если в таблице 0 записей, то необходимо вернуть пустую выборку.

Это несколько упрощенная постановка задачи. Реально необходимо сравнивать значения f1, умножив на какую-либо маску (имеется в виду логическое умножение или конъюнкция). Например, берем маску 0x10. Тогда

```
(3 & 0x10) == (2 & 0x10)
```

Т.е. имеем таблицу

```
dtime      f1
10:00      1
10:01      2
10:02      4
10:03      4
10:04      2
10:05      7
```

Необходимо выбрать по маске 0x10 следующее:

```
10:00      (f1 & 0x10) = 0
10:01      (f1 & 0x10) = 2
10:02      (f1 & 0x10) = 0
10:04      (f1 & 0x10) = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ДЕРЖИ ВЕЛОСИПЕД

```
SELECT dtime, f1
FROM (Select discrete_archive.id, discrete_archive.dtime, discrete_archive.f1, 
IFNULL(t1.f1,discrete_archive.f1-1) as ff1
FROM discrete_archive
LEFT JOIN
(Select id, f1
FROM discrete_archive) as `t1`
on discrete_archive.id=t1.id+1 ) as t2
WHERE  f1!=ff1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(f1), dtime from 'table'
```

Comment: Это не подойдет - к примеру, ряд 1,2,3,4,2,3,5 - вы получите 12345, а должны получить 1234235.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, это не то, что нужно.  

Нужно применить DISTINCT только к элементам, идущим подряд.  

Выборка из первого примера должна быть

    10:00      1
    10:01      2
    10:02      4
    10:04      2
    10:05      7

select distinct(f1), dtime from 'table' вернет 

    10:00      1
    10:01      2
    10:02      4
    10:05      7

Comment: Ну, тогда выбирайте по порядку, выбрали первое, сохранили значения и при выборе следующего проверяйте значение.

Comment: Нужно все сделать средствами MySQL за один запрос.

Comment: У вас каждое поле имеет уникальный номер?

Comment: Не понял. Что значит уникальный номер?

Comment: Например, id у них есть?

Comment: Поле id есть. Скрипт создания таблице в тексте вопроса.